# Proper way to get value from Wordpress customize control

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm currently woking on a Wordpress Theme and trying to add a customize setting control. I have a functions.php where I add a setting and control like this:

```
//  =============================
//  = Radio Input               =
//  =============================
$wp_customize->add_setting('radio_input', array(
    'default'        => 'value2',
    'capability'     => 'edit_theme_options',
    'type'           => 'theme_mod',
));

$wp_customize->add_control('themename_color_scheme', array(
    'label'      => __('Radio Input', 'themename'),
    'section'    => 'themename_color_scheme',
    'settings'   => 'radio_input',
    'type'       => 'radio',
    'choices'    => array(
        'value1' => 'Choice 1',
        'value2' => 'Choice 2',
        'value3' => 'Choice 3',
    ),
));
```

and it works. I can choose the option in the Theme Customizer in Wordpress. 
Now I want to check in my main document, which choice is selected - but I don't get any values back. Here is the code to echo the choices array.

```
 <?php 
    echo get_theme_mod('radio_input'); 
 ?>
```

And even if I change the setting type (Checkbox, Text Input, Dropdown) I never get any value back. If I echo a string (for testing purpose) I will see the string but I can't get the values from the setting control. What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think, that section id and control id should be different. In your code are the same:

```
// CONTROL ID HERE IS THE SAME, AS SECTION ID 'themename_color_scheme'
$wp_customize->add_control('themename_color_scheme', array(
    'label'      => __('Radio Input', 'themename'),
    'section'    => 'themename_color_scheme',   // SECTION ID
    'settings'   => 'radio_input',
    'type'       => 'radio',
    'choices'    => array(
        'value1' => 'Choice 1',
        'value2' => 'Choice 2',
        'value3' => 'Choice 3',
    ),
));
```

**Works for me:** (this should help for '*classic*' control types, e.g. text)

```
//  =============================
//  = Text Input                =
//  =============================
$wp_customize->add_setting('__UNIQUE_SETTING_ID__', array(  // <-- Setting id
    'capability'     => 'edit_theme_options',
    'type'           => 'theme_mod',
));

$wp_customize->add_control('__UNIQUE_CONTROL_ID__', array(  // <-- Control id
    'label'          => __('Text Input', 'themename'),
    'section'        => '__UNIQUE_SECTION_ID__',            // <-- Section id
    'settings'       => '__UNIQUE_SETTING_ID__'             // Refering to the settings id
));
```

**! But !** In case of select type (radio type is probably the same case) i still didn't get value. Here helped me [this article](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress-theme-customizer-methodology-for-sections-settings-and-controls-part-2--wp-33252), where control id is the same as setting id:

```
//  =============================
//  = Select Input              =
//  =============================
$wp_customize->add_setting('__UNIQUE_SETTING_ID__', array(  // <-- Setting id
    'default'        => 'value2',
    'capability'     => 'edit_theme_options',
    'type'           => 'theme_mod',
));

$wp_customize->add_control('__UNIQUE_SETTING_ID__', array(  // <-- THE SAME Setting id
    'label'          => __('Select Input', 'themename'),
    'section'        => '__UNIQUE_SECTION_ID__',            // <-- Section id
    // 'settings'     => '__UNIQUE_SETTING_ID__',           // Ignoring settings id here
    'type'           => 'select',
    'choices'        => array(
        'value1'        => 'Choice 1',
        'value2'        => 'Choice 2',
        'value3'        => 'Choice 3',
    ),
));
```